# create sections in class pages with doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I want to document a class that has many methods.
My methods are grouped: for example, I've four methods that allows me to change the shape of a geometric form, other five methods that allows me to fill the shape, and so on.

I'd like to know if there's a way to use something like '@section' for my purpouse, because in doxygen documentation (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsection) I've seen that this command work only in related page documentation.

How can I create logical section for classes?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `@name`, which is specifically made to group methods.

Alternatively you can use `@defgroup` and `@addtogroup` if you want the group of methods to appear on a separate page.

See http://www.doxygen.org/grouping.html for examples of both commands.

Comment: The doxygen link is broken. I believe this is the link: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html